How can I apply the Final type hint when unpacking a tuple?
The following code:
from typing import Final

host, sep, port = cast(tuple[Final, Final, Final], netloc.partition(":"))

is rejected by mypy:
test.py:20: error: Final can be only used as an outermost qualifier in a variable annotation  [valid-type]

Is there any way to define host, sep and port as Final and assign to them by unpacking a tuple in the same line of code?

Possible duplicate: Python: declare type of multiple variables in the same line. This is currently not possible. However, if you use Pyright, you can use uppercase names for the variables so that they are considered constants.
